# Archlinux: Where I can find gcc-4.4-multilib?

Tags: android, arch-linux, make, gcc, gnu

As in the topic, I can't find it in AUR, there is only gcc-4.4 or gcc-4.5-multilib. I need gcc-4.4-multilib because of Android compilation.

Or if you know - is there any way to compile Android with gcc-4.7-multilib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android source comes with an embedded toolchain, as explained on the [android-dls wiki](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Compiling_for_Android). I would use it directly.

Answer (score 3):

I've prepared a package of gcc 4.4.6 multilib:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=63316